# null replace into string in hiberante

Tags: java, gson

I have below string output :

```
["Kolkata","data can be, null",null,"05/31/2020",null]
```

but I want to have the output like below format in Java

```
["Kolkata","data can be, null","","05/31/2020",""]
```

please help me .

I am converting object to json data . Please see the below codes

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
List<Object[]> data =query.list();          
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    Object[] row = (Object[]) data.get(i);

    String  jsonString = gson.toJson(row);
    test.add(jsonString);
}
```

I want to apply this on jsonString variable using java 7 as not using java 8

Comment: So in short you want to replace null with empty string? Why not iterate over row Objects, and replace null with empty string? Is there anything more to this problem?

Comment: Your example output is a single String or is it an array/list of Strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace every null value with an empty string inside the array using another for loop. Here is an example that will do the same.

```
Object[] row = new Object[]{"Kolkata","data can be, null",null,"05/31/2020",null};
for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
    if (row[i] == null) {
        row[i] = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you..It worked ..i was trying to replace null after json convert.

Answer (score 1):

Gson doesn't allow you to change the serialized form of strings.

Probably better to change your objects -> replace null by empty string before serialization.